# What is proper way to resolve Mass Assignment in belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Assume that i have two models :

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  attr_accessible :content

  validates :content, :category, :presence => true

end
```

and

```
class category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :articles
end
```

I am creating a form to add new article and in this form a want to give a user possibility to select one category from list.

```
= form_for([:admin,@article] , :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f|


  = f.label :category
  = f.collection_select(:category, Category.all, :id, 
       :name,{:prompt => 'select category'}, {:style => 'height:50px;'})

  = f.label :content
  = f.text_area :content, class: 'tinymce', cols:60, rows: 15
  %hr

  = f.submit 'send'
```

When i submit form i've getting error Can't mass-assign protected attributes: category , which i understand.
To resolve problem i've add category_id to Article's attr_accessible and change the form to :

```
= f.label :category_id
 = f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, 
  :name,{:prompt => 'select category'}, {:style => 'height:50px;'})
```

Then everything works fine (i can create Article object with associated category_id in db) but i dont think is a proper way.
Below is my create action in ArticlesController

```
def create
    @article = Article.new(params[:article])
    if @article.save
      redirect_to([:admin,@article])
    else
      render 'new'
    end

  end
```

Can someone explain me how to improve this.

Comment: I wonder is it weird that after added 'belongs_to :category' i have to also add category_id to attr_accesible to save an object

Comment: it's a mean for security for you actually to realize what you are allowing to do within a request by defining a whitelist for attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to make the attribute mass assignable, you will need to call it directly using its name:

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(params[:article][:content])
  @article.category_id = params[:article][:category_id]
  if @article.save
    redirect_to([:admin,@article])
  else
    render 'new'
  end

end
```

In this case, the mass-assignment vulnerability seems minor, so leaving it available is probably OK. What you want to avoid is exposing any attributes where a user could maliciously set attributes of your model (such as a user.admin flag) by sending an arbitrary form POST.